# When retraining a model are you adding a layer or changing existing node values?

Tags: neural-networks, models

I am a little confused, lets take Stable Diffusion for example. I download the SD model and I then retrain for a specific art style. Am I adding a layer of nodes on top of SD or am I changing all the weights and biases on the original model?

Comment: You can do either one.

Answer (score 1):

By default, you are changing the weights and biases of the original model.
But it depends on the training method you choose. If you do LoRA training, they add extra weights to the model.